# Python: how to groupby a dataframe while keeping the information?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` like the following

```
df
    A   B
0   1  Tom
1   1  Alice
2   2  Sarah
3   3  Jack
```

I would like to groupby and count on `A` and have something like the following

```
df
    A   count  names
0   1     2    Tom, Alice
1   2     1    Sarah
2   3     1    Jack
```

Comment: `df.groupby('A').agg(count=('A','size'),names=('B',', '.join)).reset_index()`

Comment: @Erfan it gives me an error `TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
`

Comment: That means you dont have the latest `pandas` version, I suggest you update. Else use `df.groupby('A').agg({'A':'size', 'B': ', '.join}).rename({'A':'count'}, axis=1).reset_index()`